# Launcher icon for FireOS 5.2.4.0

Tags: icons, amazon-fire-tv, app-launcher

Recently my firtv got updated and the now the OS version is 5.2.4.0

actually the problem which i am facing about the launcher icon. Previously i was using launcher icon in menisfest with :

```
android:icon : 144 x 144 dimension.
android:banner : 319 x 180 dimension.
```

Now for FireOS version 5.2.4.0 what should be the size of launcher icon ?

Answer (score 0):

the new asset sizes are described at https://developer.amazon.com/public/solutions/devices/fire-tv/docs/asset-guidelines-for-app-submission

Small icon is 114x114px
Large icon is 512x512px
and the new App Icon is 1280x720px and is uploaded via the developer portal